# Can I compile selected headers code in C

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

I have a code in C that uses ocilib and mysql headers .
on some of my machine I don't have ocilib or mysql , and I want to be able to select to compile my code with/without the headers , can I do that ?
need to say that the code has ocilib and mysql defined in it, so probably I'll want to put them out too when compiling.

example :

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ocilib.h>


void main(){
MYSQL *conn;
OCI_Connection* cn;
OCI_Statement* st;
char *db_type=NULL;
.....
....
if (strcasestr(db_type,"mysql")){/* mysql */
if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, db_host,db_user, db_password, db_schemata, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        syslog (LOG_NOTICE,"%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        return;
    }
....
}else{/* oracle*/
OCI_Initialize(NULL, NULL, OCI_ENV_DEFAULT);
....
}
}
```

I hope I was clear enough..
thanks !

Comment: If your code compiles without certains headers, why do you include them in first place? But I doubt your code compiles if you don't include ocilib.h.

Comment: cause on some machine I dont have ocilib installed , and on some machines I dont have mysql installed..

Comment: How do you expect to compile code that uses ocilib, when the ocilib headers are not available ? It's almost like expecting to be able to compile your C code when there is no C compiler available.

Comment: I think you'll have to create a kind of dummy implementation of oclib/mysql

Comment: ok , got it. used `#define` and `#ifdef` and now everything works. Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert conditional compilation directives (`#ifdef` ... `#endif` being canonical) into the code to selectively enable or disable compilation of the relevant `#include` directives.  As @MichaelWalz observed in comments, however, suppressing just the headers probably breaks the rest of the code -- if it doesn't then you should just delete those `#include`s.

Moreover, if you do not have the headers in a particular environment, then it seems likely that you also do not have the libraries containing the functions declared by those headers.  Supposing that you include the headers because your code relies on some of those functions, you won't then be able to link the program once you compile it, headers or no headers.

A conditional compilation solution thus only works if you use it everywhere needed in your code to remove all reliance on the features of a given library, including the associated headers.  That approach is relatively common, but it is not easy to retrofit onto a system not initially designed for it.

Comment: ok , got it.
used `#define` and `#ifdef` and now everything works.
Thanks guys !